# new to using bootstrap and setting a background of 2 colours

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm new to learning web development and using bootstrap, I've got my basic layout for my webpage and looking to set the background colour of my div section to 2 colours in the row formation and wondering how I would go about it.

and making it work with the shrinking and enlarging the screen without causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be a bit more specific and add some code to your question.

Based on what I gather, is this what you're looking for (original Codepen for a different Bootstrap solution): [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jeffberlin/pen/mdeMqKP)

```css
.row {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, green 50%, red 50%);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid"> <!-- can also use .container -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

You can also use CSS and assign a class/id to the `div` and then add the `background-color` as you would for anything else

Comment: thanks for the help with the setting of the background colour, I'll make a note for future to add code snippets, to better help the people providing help.

Comment: No worries. Was my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: on the code how would I run the green along the top and the red under the green but increase the thickness of the red i.e. takes up more than 1 row

Comment: For red under green: `.row { background: linear-gradient(0deg, green 50%, red 50%); }`. And can you be more specific? (overflow the row from the bottom into a new div, overflow the top, etc.) If you could generate a picture or example of what you're trying to do, that would be best.

Answer (score 0):

your goal here can be achieved through 2 ways.

**First Mehtod:** 
You can use bootstrap for this such as the following code snippet

```
  <div class="bg-success">
    This changes the background-color to green
</div>
```

You can also use other colors such as primary for blue, danger for red etc. To learn more about colors check out this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/

**The Second Method you can use is CSS**

Note: You can use both Inline styles or stylesheets for this purpose.

THIS IS AN INLINE STYLE:

```
    <div style="background-color: yellow;">
This div has a background-color of yellow
</div>
```

You can also use a stylesheet:

**This is the HTML**

```
<div class="colors">
This div has an orange color
</div>
```

**This is the CSS**

```
div.colors{
background-color: orange
}
```

You can switch the color 'orange' that is used in the background-color property to any of the colors that you like. I would suggest using CSS for this since it has a variety of colors to offer.

Comment: thanks for the help, id possibly go the CSS route on the code to make it cleaner rather than the inline style

Comment: Your welcome modzking4, I'm glad that I could help.